# javascript regex to find image urls in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a Javascript regEx to parse a database field for image urls and format them for output - so far, I have been using

```
input = input.replace(/(https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)(.*))(\w|$)/ig, "<br><img style='max-width:100%;overflow:hidden;' src='$1'>");
```

and its been serving me well.  All png, jpe?g and gif references get replaced by IMG tags and images show in the output stream as intended.

However, I've been thrown a loop.

I've noticed some urls (notably those from Facebook CDN - though I supposed others could also be doing this as well) have appended a whole pile of "stuff" after the image type ...  stuff that if not present results in the files not being available, and a missing image icon gets produced.  For example, this is a valid picture url from fbcdn.net:

```
https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11147160_10156300867440377_5455334309678688318_n.jpg?oh=916e68ac2c908bbe15961825c373d6bc&oe=5606B6F4
```

Can someone suggest a change/improvement to the regEx that would pick up the extra trailing characters?  Or is another method of attack necessary

(I personally like the global regEx as I can nail all of the instances in the stream at once... having to manually parse the stream is not something I would look forward to...)

**Update:** I understand there is some ambiguity in the request - hopefully this will clarify.

I need to pull out any image url - regardless of the "stuff" after the image extention.   It could be the first item in the text string, or the last, or embedded somewhere in the middle.

The processing is done in Javascript.  I am currently using this as my validity test.  All images within it are valid urls pulled from Google image search.

```
http://well-being.esdc.gc.ca/misme-iowb/auto/diagramme-chart/stg2/c_4_21_6_1_eng.png?20150508104424447 This is arbitrary text https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11147160_10156300867440377_5455334309678688318_n.jpg?oh=916e68ac2c908bbe15961825c373d6bc&oe=5606B6F4 this is arbitrary text

http://lh6.ggpht.com/-1Rua79J-EDo/TwuyZkHwcmI/AAAAAAAADvA/ENfg1TeayvU/type_catalog_error_thumb%25255B1%25255D.jpg?imgmax=800 this is arbitrary text http://image.slidesharecdn.com/top5thingstodoafteranaccident-140826163850-phpapp02/95/top-five-things-to-do-after-any-type-of-accident-causing-injury-1-638.jpg?cb=1409089267
```

Hopefully this sheds sufficient light into the types of variations I may encounter  (The only one I know for sure is the FBCDN - I'm basing the others on knowledge of what else I've seen out there... so a generalized solution is needed, not one specific to FBCDN).

Thank you to all that offer suggestions...

Comment: To catch the optional question mark and the rest, you would use `(\?blabla)?` but typing this almost sounds too easy. Is there a problem?

Comment: @MrLister - yes, the problem was I was staring at it too long and getting nowhere with my testing on regexpal.com .. all the variations I tried were either too greedy, or not greedy enough. 

The FB urls have some consistency - but I'm sure I should be limiting myself to this. I've also seen a few (example not available, sorry) where there is sizing info appended, and others who seem to append a timestamp (for a cache?)  Who knows what evil concoctions others have put in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Updated after OP updated with more example input.*

There are three issues with your attempt: boundaries of your matches, using '.*' and missing pattern for legal postfix.

The dot star notation is a bad idea in RegEx, which the article "[Death to Dot Star!](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=24640)" illustrates quite well. Use negated character classes instead, and here I chose "\S*?" which is "any character that is **not** a whitespace". If you try replacing that with ".*?" instead on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vS2jJ4/7), you can see it failing to match properly (it includes a link that is not an image).

Since it is all in the same string, boundries must be defined for the match, and since whitespace is sufficient "\b" does the trick nicely. This also removes the need for the "(.*)" and "(\w|$)" parts.

The last thing you missed was the legal endings to the url, and there are two solutions to this: Either define what you think is plausible to include most scenarios and have no false positives, or include anything but have a chance of getting too many results.

Wrap it all together, and you are left with these two different approaches:

### Solution 1 - define what is correct

```
\b(https?:\/\/\S*?\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif)
  # allowed postfixes to the filetype
  (?:\?(?:
    # alphnumeric key/value pairs
    (?:(?:[\w_-]+=[\w_-]+)(?:&[\w_-]+=[\w_-]+)*)|
    # alphnumeric postfix
    (?:[\w_-]+)
  ))?
)\b
```

*Try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vS2jJ4/7)*

### Solution 2 - use whitespace as the only factor

```
\b(https?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpe?g|gif)\S*)\b
```

*Try it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vS2jJ4/8)*

Comment: your regex101 link is corrupted

Comment: that's what I thought ;)

Comment: @johnySkovdal - I was ready to mark this as answer... but then I saw it matched only to the FB url... something simpler such as 

`http://example.com/blah.jpg?fred` 

fails  As I said to Mr. Lister above - I cant be sure what evil things others have done out there.

Comment: @ScottBrown: Which is why I asked you to provide us with a better example input. It seems that you only show us the bit of the input that you have trouble parsing. Without knowing what else can be in the input, it is impossible to write a correct regex. E.g. from the sample you gave, ".*" would be correct.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - Thank you for your suggestion. I've updated with a better example which shows more variety in placement and content.   I wont guarantee that there are not other varieties of url that might be encountered.

I've forked your regex101 test to https://regex101.com/r/zN8nZ1/1 which unfortunately shows that its unfortunately too greedy, and includes the arbitrary text that surrounds the urls (this is where my own attempts got stuck).

Comment: No reason to fork it, just save in the same. It has full history. You forked version 2 instead of version 3, but I'm updating my answer with version 5 that seems to fit yours and better: https://regex101.com/r/vS2jJ4/5

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - Thank you ... that picks out all my test scenarios perfectly.  I've marked this as answer. 

I'm going to have to digest that later (I really like how that regex101 site explains things - I'd been using http://regexpal.com/ which is an antique in comparison)

Comment: @ScottBrown: See my updated answer for better explanation, as well as simpler alternative solution, if whitespace really is good enough as delimiter.